# Rename index.html file generated from npm run build - Create-React-App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am using Create-React-App template as boilerplate template. When npm run build command is executed, it generates a index.html file. Is there a way to rename this file to default.html as part of build process by adding configuration in package.json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you throw something similar to [this code](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback) into a javascript file you can execute it at the end of the build.

Say you called the js file `rename.js` and it's in the same directory that you're running the npm command from you would add `&& node rename` at the end of the `build` script command in `package.json`.

Comment: You can also use the `mv` command at the end of the `build` script in `package.json`: `"build": "react-scripts build && mv build/index.html build/default.html"`. Then there's no need to create the `rename.js` file.